# Has anyone added discounting functionality to the 'cart' component of CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent

I am testing/trying to use CiviEvent 'shopping cart' (needs to be enabled using CiviEvent Component Settings under Administer/CiviEvent) mode of registering for events and while I am on an older version of Civi I looked at 4.6 code and it looks about the same re: Cart functionality. I have modified Cart code to allow for using CiviDiscount, if an event is configured to allow discounts - is anyone else interested in this? I will submit a patch if so. (there are other features that seem lacking in Cart, I will include a README to document)

Comment: hi Lesley, I really thought that CiviDiscount and CiviEvent's shopping cart were compatible, but after testing I have found some issues.

Comment: Should there be a new answer to this saying "yes this is possible now"?

Answer (score 2):

This might an important feature for folks using Event Cart functionality. It would be great if you can submit a PR against CiviDiscount repository at

> https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount

Comment: Because the Cart modules (ParticipantsandPrices, Payment.php) are not modeled on regular Event/Registration modules, I couldn't simply add Cart form names to _cividiscount - I called in _cividiscount methods in Cart.  I understand that no one supports Cart code as part of core CiviCRM, yet it isn't an extension? Should I  rewrite Cart to 'fit' CiviDiscount in the way Event/Reg is done?

Comment: OK, I submitted a PR for this in CiviDiscount and it will be added- it needs a PR in Event/Cart/Form/Checkout too, which I also submitted

Comment: If you think Cart code changes will be an improvement, then go for it. Alternatively you can also submit the PR against CiviDiscount repo.

Comment: Lesley or Kurund - I just looked through PR requests to see if i could see an outcome from this work but failed. Can anyone update this thread?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for this. It would definitely be a useful feature, so please submit a PR.

I think the best way to share desired features is via the issue queue for the extension at https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/issues. Perhaps separate each suggestion into a different issue. That will make it easier to manage the suggestion, and to cite the issue when submitting a PR implementing a new feature.

Comment: As I commented to Kurund Jalmi, the problem is more with the Cart code- if it were modeled on the Event Registration code I could fairly easily add the correct form name to CiviDiscount to add the input textbox for the code, and enable it for applicable events/pricesets, but it is Cart code that needs re-writing. I added calls to _cividiscount_* to implement discounting in Cart/Form/Checkout modules